# How can I store two API values in MYSQL Point

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial, opengis

I receive lan and lot data from an API in PHP and extract them from the response with `($jsonData[0]['lat']);` and `$jsonData[0]['lon']);`. How can I add them two my MySQL column `location` as a POINT value?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't simply storing those two separate values in the database so the raw data can be supplied in whichever form you desire when the application needs it?

Comment: No, there isn't - I thought Point is intended for location data?

Comment: I always prefer storing data independently of how it's being used. Gives you flexibility for the future. But it really depends on your use case. What kind of operations are you looking to perform on this data?

Comment: I will later use this data to show datrabase entries on a leaflet.js map

Comment: I haven't used that library, but as far as I can see from the demo, coordinates are supplied separately. So I would advocate storing them separately. Makes little sense to receive separate coordinates, join them into a point, only to extract individual coordinates from the point.

Comment: Okay, then this question is answered. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, somehow when I try to add `$latitude = $jsonData[0]['lat']);` and `$longitude = $jsonData[0]['lon']);` the PHP breaks - any ideas?

Comment: The trailing parenthesis?

Comment: please imagine my facepalm right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's geometry stuff offers the  [`ST_GeomFromText()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html). You can use it like this.

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.7488 -73.9854)')
```

Notice that `'POINT(40.7488 -73.9854)'` is a text string, and that there's no comma between the two numbers.

If you do something like this to make one of those text strings

```
$pointText = "POINT(" . $jsonData[0]['lat'] . " " .  $jsonData[0]['lon'] . ")";
```

then you can do an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (geocolumn) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(?));
```

with $pointText as the parameter.

With MySQL versions prior to 8, I agreed with @El_Vanja's suggestion of using separate `FLOAT` columns for lat / long. But with version 8, MySQL has the ability to handle spherical as well as cartesian coordinate systems, so the spatial index can be very useful.